# Django + React Development Setup for a Hybrid App

Tags: reactjs, django, installation

I'm using Django + React hybrid setup. Django does not simply act as a backend to API but actually renders pages. The setup works in production with some urls routed to Django's templating system and others (starting with 'app/') rendered from index.html + static files from React build.

This works in production. However, I'm trying to get Django development server (localhost:8000) work with react development server (localhost:3000) as follows.

**Django backend**

**Urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # React urls
    re_path(r'^app/.*',views.application,name='application'),
    # Django urls
    path("", include("my_app.urls")),
]
```

**Views.py**

```py
def application(request, upstream='http://127.0.0.1:3000'):
    upstream_url = upstream + request.path
    with urllib.request.urlopen(upstream_url) as response:
        content_type = response.headers.get('Content-Type')
        # print('CONTENT TYPE: ',content_type)
        if content_type == 'text/html; charset=UTF-8':
            response_text = response.read().decode()
            content = engines['django'].from_string(response_text).render()
        else:
            content = response.read()
        return HttpResponse(
            content,
            content_type=content_type,
            status=response.status,
            reason=response.reason,
        )
```

**React frontend**

**App.js**

```js
function App() {
  const HomePage = () => {
  return (<h1>Home Page</h1>);
  }
  const TestPage= () => {
    return (<h1>Test Page</h1>);
  };
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="app/" element = {<HomePage/>}/>
        <Route path="app/test" element = {<TestPage/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

**.env**

```js
PUBLIC_URL = app
```

Both **/app** and **app/test** urls are accessible on port 3000. However, on port 8000 where Django development server is running I can only get **/app** while **app/test** returns HTTP Error 404: Not Found. Setting PUBLIC_URL to **app/test** enables access to that url but not **/app**.

Any idea how this could be set up properly?